# Syntax Error in Python Requests library for the identifier "headers"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build  a webscraper from a tutorial I watched.
Replicating the same work is giving me the following error.

```
import requests
import bs4
r = requests.get("http://www.pyclass.com/example.html", headers={"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"})  
c=r.content
```

The error says "Syntax Error : Invalid character in identifier" 
The word `headers` is being highlighted .

I really need to use headers so that I can fetch the data by impersonating a web browser , otherwise I am getting a 406 error without it.

Comment: Only Python can give syntax errors, not libraries (AFAIK). I don't get a syntax error from that by putting it through a linter. What's the full error message?

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code in? I don't see a syntax error offhand

Comment: I didnt see any errors either. https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/670d3c8a-6d99-47fb-8614-04028d96a3a2/?i=true

Comment: I forgot to mention, I changed the code in the question, but I assume it was only a formatting problem since the way it was written, you would have gotten `IndentationError: unexpected indent` and `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` before hitting the error you mentioned.

Comment: With the code as it is in the question right now, there is no issue - the code runs and fetches the page correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code.

```
import requests
head={"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"}
r=requests.get("http://www.example.com/", headers=head)
```

Comment: Please [edit] to explain, how does this fix the problem?

Comment: Thanks ! I the error was a space before the word "headers" ... (._.")